# Comparing script for random intercept and slope independent between nlme and lme4

Tags: r, lme4, nlme, random-effects

So for random mixed effects, I am making a comparison list of scripts between the 2 packages.

For independent random intercept and slope, if I am using the following code in lme4 package, what is the corresponding script in nlme?

```
model1 <- lmer(y~A + (1+site) + (0+A|site), data, REML = FALSE)
```

Also, for nested mixed effects, which calculates the random effect in different way from the above, are my scripts correct?

```
model2 <- lme(y~A, random = ~1+site/A, data, method="REML")
```

and

```
model3 <- lmer(y~A + (1|site) + (1|site:A), data, method=FALSE)
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer is not too late!

For your first model the version in `nlme` would be:

```
model1 <-  lme(y ~ A , 
       random = list(A = pdDiag(~time)),
       data=data)
```

Your seccond and third models are equivalent. Model 3 in `lme4` package can be also written as:

```
 model3 <- lmer(y~A + (1|site/A), data, method=FALSE)
```

I foud this link that might help you a lot to compare `nlme` and `lme4` packages

https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer#conditional-growth-model-dropping-intercept-slope-covariance